JOIN vs. WHERE Special Case - Single Target Foreign Key
Consider:

table A with primary key "id" and unique key "name"
table B with foreign key "aid" referencing A."id"
function (plpgsql) "f_name2id" taking some "name" and returning the matching "id"

Which of the following would be more efficient?

SELECT * FROM B WHERE "aid" = f_name2id(<some_name>);
SELECT B.* FROM B INNER JOIN A ON B."aid" = A."id" WHERE A."name" = <some_name>;


The second query has to perform better. The first query just hard-codes the nested loop join that the second query will most likely perform anyway, and it has the overhead of an additional function call.

Interesting. I though the function would extract the single "aid" value needed instead of hardcoding a join.

It seems that when the function f_name2id is IMMUTABLE there is not much difference in performance (test with ~10k rows in A and ~10M rows in B.

I am not saying that there need be much difference, but the join is better.
